# Why am I unable to install a constraint on my view?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate a button from outside the visible bounds of my `UIViewController` to the center of it. I have a constraint setup in my storyboard called `myButtonLeading` which I remove as part of my animation, and then I want to add a new constraint called `newCenterConstraint`.

```
@IBAction func updateDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        let newCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myButton, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        self.myButton.removeConstraint(self.myButtonLeading)
        self.myButton.addConstraint(newCenterConstraint)

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

The code I have right now is giving me the following error message regarding my reference to `toItem: view`.

> Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture
>   semantics explicit

But when I used `self.view` my app crashes with an error message saying:

> Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference
>   something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

Where am I going wrong here in adding the new centerX constraint?

Comment: Is the button's superview related to self.view ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is very clear. You are adding a constraint referencing `self.view` to a subview of `self.view`.

To fix this replace this line:

```
self.myButton.addConstraint(newCenterConstraint)
```

With:

```
self.view.addConstraint(newCenterConstraint)
```

A better approach though, as suggested by Lou Franco, is to instead of animating the addition of a new constraint, changing the constant of the center x constraint and animating the `layoutIfNeeded` function. (For this you’d have to connect an outlet for the center x constraint.)

It would look like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
  self.centerConstraint.constant = 0
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. There were simpler shortcuts for this, but none of them seemed like the smartest solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a centerX constraint with a constant to offset it offscreen.  Then animate setting the constant to 0.